# Schedule a Twilio Call with Iron.io

Tags: python, ruby, twilio, iron.io

I'm attempting to schedule a call to be made at a particular time. The following python code makes the call:

```
#Download the library from twilio.com/docs/libraries
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Get these credentials from http://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "myaccountsid"
auth_token = "myauthtoken"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

# Make the call
call = client.calls.create(to="+12345789123",  # Any phone number
                           from_="+12345789123", # Must be a valid Twilio number
                           url="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient")
print call.sid
```

and this code is a .worker used for Iron.io:

```
# define the runtime language
runtime "python"

gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'uber_config'

# exec is the file that will be executed:
exec "makecall.py"
```

Using this [tutorial](http://blog.iron.io/2012/10/how-to-schedule-sms-and-calls-on-twilio.html).

However, I receive the following exception:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:103:in `eval': undefined method `gem' for #<IronWorkerNG::Code::Base:0x007fd6c5008ec8> (NoMethodError)
    from (eval):4:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:103:in `eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/fetcher.rb:78:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/fetcher.rb:78:in `fetch'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:93:in `block in initialize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:92:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/code/base.rb:92:in `initialize'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/cli.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/lib/iron_worker_ng/cli.rb:78:in `upload'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/iron_worker_ng-1.6.2/bin/iron_worker:120:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/iron_worker:23:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/iron_worker:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is apparent that this is a typo. the gem name is `twilio-ruby`

Comment: @akonsu isn't that what I typed?

Comment: I am saying the tutorial has a typo. Perhaps they ported it from a ruby version.

Comment: @akonsu what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: @Apollo what command are you running that gives this error?

Comment: Also can you post all the output including the command you entered.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the code from the tutorial and it worked fine on `iron_worker upload sms`.

Comment: Oh, I just realized what's going on, will put into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use Ruby gems in your `.worker` file with a python script. You should be using pip for Python libraries. Try changing your `.worker` file to this:

```
runtime 'python'

# dependencies
pip 'twilio'

# executable
exec 'mycall.py'
```